# Why does my jest mock function doesn't get executed with mock object while using enzyme's "mount" function?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Following Problem:

I have this component:

```
const TodoHeader = ({ handleChange, handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="your todo.."
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

with following test:

```
it("should call the passed in handleSubmit function with the event object", () => {
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<TodoHeader handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />);
    const form = wrapper.find("form");
    console.log(form.debug());
    const mockEvent = { target: {} };

    form.simulate("submit", mockEvent);

    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockEvent);
    // Why does this work with shallow but not with mount?
  });
```

This will fail because the function has been called with the actual onSubmit event. Altough I'm mocking it with my custom object.

**When I do the same with `shallow` instead of `mount` it will pass**

I don't get why.

Here is a little codesandbox with the the same to test around.

https://codesandbox.io/s/72yl24j59q

Comment: `simulate` isn't a recommended way to do this any way. If you test submit event, trigger `props.onSubmit()` directly.

Comment: so it's like `wrapper.props.handleSubmit()` and then I can check if it had been called right? Why isn't simulate recommended?

Comment: It's more like formWrapper.props.onSubmit(). simulate will be deprecated soon AIK, because it's excessive. It doesn't really simulate DOM, just calls a respective handler internally.

Comment: Ah okay I understand. I get it now. I have to reference the form first. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t have to test if onSubmit works with the event object you pass - that’d be testing React itself, and the browser, which isn’t your concern.

I have updated the codesandbox link you provided and as per that testing all the test cases are passed now.

https://codesandbox.io/s/0op31650rp

All you have to test is when you pass a mock function, that is being triggered after form submit.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of that. I thought I have to test it because I pass it manually in the function received from props. But now that I see it that way you are right :) Thx. How do my tests look in general? Just started learning testing and this is with what I came up so far. They are considered unit tests right?

Comment: @GeraltDieSocke Glad I could help. Yeah these are called unit test and the one I can see in this question looks fine :)

Comment: Thank you, appreciated! Glad it doesn't suck :)

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing please? My first test, how would I test this with a snapshot? I know that it saves the state of the app and compares it next time. But how do i get the initial correct "snapshot" it should be matched against?